# Puzzling why variable fails to update, causing the dreaded HardFault?

Tags: variables, malloc, stm32, keil

I'm migrating to STM32, debugging STM32F103C8T6 with Keil MDK5, running at 72 MHz. Total RAM is less than 200 bytes only, C99 mode enabled. I have a function as shown below, which I do not understand why the variable `new_data_Length` fails to update most of the time, remains as ZERO, causing the HardFault exception caught by `HardFault_Handler()`. Being a newbie in STM32 and Keil MDK, maybe there's something I'm missing. Any ideas?

```c
uint8_t size_A = 22; // globally declared
uint8_t data_Length = someValue; // globally declared

someFunction(dData, data_Length, size_A);
.
.
```

in other file...

```c
void someFunction(uint8_t* rData, uint8_t dLength, uint8_t sizeA)
{
  uint8_t new_data_Length = dLength + sizeA + 1;
  unit8_t newData[new_data_Length]; // <<--malloc fails because new_Data_Length is 0

  // unit8_t* newData;
  // newData = malloc(new_data_Length); // <<--malloc fails here too... 
  // if (newData == 0) 
  // {
  .
  .
  .

}
```

Comment: Try to define your two global variables as volatile. This tells the compiler that they can change everytime and force the generate code to reload the values on accessing them.

Comment: When you say in other file does it mean you use extern for these global variables?

Comment: @veeman. thanks but it doesn't help.

Comment: @phodina. Of course. When I said I was a newbie in STM32 and Keil MDK, I didn't mean I was a total beginner. I came from MChip PIC asm, xC, VS C#, VS C++, Android Studio, NetBeans Java....

Comment: @sambyte Just checking. Can you put breakpoint on someFunction and query the values being passed and verify you actually pass in the defined values at compile time. I would also suggest not to use global variables as they can change at any given time (e.g. modification in interrupt) unless they are const or for some sort of handling.

Comment: @phodina. Thanks. That was how I got to know about the variable when first notified by HardFault Handler(). Making them local also didn't help. In Keil user's guide, it says about 'init_mempool' must be initialized before declaring arrays. But that is for C166. In MDK-ARM C99 it is simply invalid. I need more reading...